# Disable scrollTop when triggering mousewheel or trackpad

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto, autoscroll

I'm using a fullscreen slider and found this little snippet:

```
jQuery(window).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(scX, 6000);
});

function scX() {  
  hPos = jQuery("#hideMe").offset().top;
  hHeight = jQuery("#hideMe").height();      
  jQuery("html, body").animate({scrollTop: +(hPos + hHeight)}, 1200);
}
```

All it does is scrolling down to the next section after 6 seconds. 
Now my question: I want to disable the snippet if the user starts scrolling before the script auto scrolls to the next section.

I hope you can help me, best regards Julian.

Comment: Put the `setTimeout` in a variable which can then be cleared using `clearTimeout` when the user starts scrolling (the scroll event).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
jQuery(window).ready(function(){
  var abc = setTimeout(scX, 3000);
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout(abc);
    });
});
```